# I want a Googlesheet to lookup and import values from api

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google sheet with a list of information on customers, one being a user count from a WaaS I run.

I would like to regularly run a script that makes a http api request that returns the user count from the platform and updates the value in the Googlesheet.

How easy is this?

Answer (score 1):

I never worked with the Google Sheets API, but the documentation looks good. I hope this will help, https://developers.google.com/sheets/